# Combine Arrays - unclear what to do

Tags: php, arrays, merge

**Var Dump**

```
var_dump($row);
```

**Output**

```
array(1) { ["company"]=> string(8) "ffr3e456" ["high_1"]=> string(8) "8.32465" }
array(2) { ["company"]=> string(8) "gg8751hw" ["high_2"]=> string(7) "7.66574" }
```

**Current code**

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    for ($p=1; $p<=2; $p++)
                         {
                         echo number_format($row["high_".$p],2);
```

The above code displays `high_1` but not `high_2`.

How do I combine the above into a single array, if it is needed?

And/ or how do I `echo` both `high_1` and `high_2`?

Thanks.

Comment: Combine or merge? What is the desired output?

Comment: Combine would be better (didn't know that was possible).

Comment: Still have no idea what you mean (it's clear for `high_x` but what about `company`?) - please provide expected output and what you already tried.

Comment: The above code can access `high_1` but doesn't display `high_2`.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56608/room-for-kingkero-and-homer-j)

Comment: @kingkero - pop that answer in, perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem here is that you have a multi query. So when you get your `$row` it contains only **one** `high_x` value, that is why you cannot iterate inside the loop.

To resolve this, you can simply merge the rows as `company` doesn't matter and can be overridden, this could look like the following

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = array_merge($data, $row);
}
```

Now `$data` should/could look like this (not necessarily in this order but shouldn't matter)

```
array(
    'company' => '...',
    'high_1' => '...',
    'high_2' => '...',
    ...
)
```